# Python - Only Odd Numbers

Tags: python-3.7

I need to find out if `n` is **made up** of odd numbers. If a number is made up of odd numbers, I should `return True`, else I should `return False`.

`n = 1357` should return `True` because all four values are odd.
`n = 1356` should return `False` because `6` is an even number.

How would I go about solving this? My first steps included looping over the "stringified" number but then I felt stuck because I was unable to use modulo to check whether or not the number is even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

If the set of odd digits is subtracted from the set of `str(n)` and the result is empty, then it was all odd digits:

```
>>> def odd(n):
...   return set(str(n))-set('13579')==set()
...
>>> odd(123)
False
>>> odd(113355)
True
```

It's fast, too, compared to checking each digit numerically:

```
C:\>py -m timeit -s "odd=set('13579');n=111333555777999" "all([int(x)%2 for x in str(n)])"
50000 loops, best of 5: 4.69 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "odd=set('13579');n=111333555777999" set(str(n))-odd==set()"
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.36 usec per loop
```

Comment: very nice! was aware of set substraction but providing the odd numbers directly as an iterable is clever.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think of it that way @Mark Tolonen!

Answer (score 0):

```
def isMadeofEven(num):
    for number in str(num):
        if (int(number) % 2 !=0):
            return False
    return True
```

- Basically loops through each characters of the converted string number and if it finds an odd returns false

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 1357
print(all([int(x)%2!=0 for x in str(n)]))
#True
```

You essentially explained a possible way already. To check if a number is even use:

number % 2